# Possibilities: Web Application through Spring MVC/Webflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, project, spring-webflow

I recently started working for a company, which has outsourced all their IT business, due to several reasons. After a few years, they've started to realize that they are constantly overcharged by some of their external partners, leading to the point where they finally decided to bring in some IT expertise to evaluate possibilities to consolidate their IT costs.

This is where I came in. After now working for 3 months in this company, my boss has suddenly offered me the possibility to re-implement some of the software, which they are currently using as a service provided by an external partner, which would take over starting 2018.

After taking a closer look at what this current software does & how it is set up, it is really incredible what this external partner is charging them for the service, so I'm really tempted to consider the offer for re-implementation. I already gathered some experience with Spring, Spring-MVC and partly Spring-Webflow, setting up a small web-application using a relational database through hibernate (although I wouldn't mind using any other Object-Relational-Mapping as well).

The question that arises now to me is, if I completely overrate the possibilities which Spring is giving me. Upfront now some of the requirements and small description of what the software needs to be capable of:

- Web Application based on a relational database server
- 10.000 users maximum, the daily access to the system is around 100-200 users only(!)
- Several roles (admin, manager, customers, end-users) with different views & workflows
- all in all several different workflows for each role
- the workflows are all based on data only, no heavy calculation or other complicated stuff, really small straightforward workflows of a typical small web application
- several smaller interfaces to export/import data, typically provided or delivered via XML/Excel/CSV files
- standard security/logging features

As far as I can tell, all this requirements could be easily fulfilled implementing this project as a Spring-MVC/WebFlow application, using the aspect-oriented security/logging approach of current Spring versions, with any modern RDBMS working in the background.

Right now, my company is paying 5-digits numbers per month for the use and service of this system (which by the way is a standard-product from that rather small external IT company, only issue is, that there are barely no other software products in this branch by other companies), while still having to pay a lot of money on top for every small change (minor changes to the workflows, changing text on existing pages).

So this is really a very tempting offer, since the software requirements are rather standard from my point of view, and in my opinion, Spring would provide a perfect base for such an application.

My main question is, am I overlooking something in the here stated requirements, which are not feasible via Spring.

Thanks ahead for any input regarding this topic, while I continue my evaluation of it by myself.

Comment: This question is really too broad for SO. I would say, however, that all applications look simple on the surface (Windows just needs to listen for mouse movement and open other programs right?) but they get significantly more complex when you get down to it. Prototype a simple CRUD application use the Spring Stack (MVC, Security, JPA, Boot) and see you how go. Be very sure you can handle the task before committing.

Comment: I know that it is a very broad question, my huge advantage is, that I'm already seeing for 3 months now what this software does, in my position at my company I'm completely included in every discussion with the developers about ongoing changes, I have complete read-access to the data structure in their database and about their workflows. It is really mind-blowing how they got to the point to charge my company these numbers, regarding what a simple application it is. Biggest advantage: They need a successor January 2018(!), so I still have enough time to evaluate before committing to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your requirements, I don't see anything in there that you couldn't reasonably easily implement using the Spring stack.

A few things that you haven't mentioned:

Start by using [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). It will vastly simplify the configuration you need to get up and running with Spring.

It would probably be best to use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) in order to handle most of your persistence needs (since as you mention you will be using a relational database)

You security and roles needs will probably be met by [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).

[Here](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan) is the code of the Spring.io website which is a real world site using the latest Spring technologies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I will definitely take a look at Spring Boot. Already have some experience with Spring Data JPA (and several other Object/Relational Mapping models, was one of my majors at the university). And thanks for the code for the Spring website, will be interesting to study their approaches to instrument Spring.